# ERROR - Invalid data source name in ... fuelPHP migration

Tags: fuelphp

I'm a pretty newbie to both MAC OS and Fuel PHP, I try to learn FuelPHP and it leaded me to some tutorials, you can find the link here:
[link](https://tutsplus.com/lesson/code-generation/)

As the tutorial show that using migration in FuelPHP by the command line:

```
oil r migrate
```

and it shows some sort of weird error which when I google (and on the tutorial too) some suggested changing the 'localhost' to '127.0.0.1' in the fuel/app/config/development/db.php file, the error should be gone.

Then it show another error which is:

```
ERROR - invalid data source name in COREPATH/classes/database/pdo/connection.php on line 87
```

Although I have checked the connection to the database via browser which is ok, all the username and password to connect to the database also correct. I still have no idea what is the problem. Please help and sorry about my English, it's not my native language.

Comment: This happens to me when the database config isn't setup properly.  Keep in mind that the environments may be different (usually the cause of this for me).  Check that oil is running in the same env that your site is.  `php oil -v` will echo out the environment mode.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem isn't really the data source name but the environnement.

You need t set the environment correctly, it's explained in this page : http://fuelphp.com/docs/general/environments.html

This is what i do in my debian :

```
env FUEL_ENV=production oil refine migrate:up
```

And what i do in my developement computer on windows :

```
set FUEL_ENV=development // One time only
oil refine migrate:up
```

Hop it will help you.

Comment: This exactly.  Fuel is complaining about having a bad data source because it's loading the database config for a different 'Environment' which either isn't defined or _is_ a bad data source.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Fuel/app/bootstrap.php and check for the line number 27 - 30 it looks some what like this

```
Fuel::$env = (isset($_SERVER['FUEL_ENV']) ? $_SERVER['FUEL_ENV'] : Fuel::DEVELOPMENT);
```

and in your case if its Fuel::DEVELOPMENT then you should ( It may be `FUEL::PRODUCTION` or `FUEL::TESTING` )

Now based on the environment do check your configuration of database connection with in the file . fuel/app/config/development/db.php

With in that file check for DB connections it will be somewhat like this , and verify whether they are correct .

```
return array(
    'default' => array(
        'connection'  => array(
            'dsn'        => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yourdatabasename',
            'username'   => 'yourusername',
            'password'   =>  'yourpassword',
        ),
    ),
);
```

I think in your case there is a mismatch between the environment set and the configuration used  .

Hope this helps